# unrecognized url in django

Tags: django, python-3.8

i created a href url for my delete link in my template  that takes in an attribute description of a Todo object but the url can't be matched to the one i passed in the path since for some reason i cant call the attribute in my url

```
def todo_delete(request, todo_description):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(description=todo_description)
    todo.delete()
    template = loader.get_template('Todo/index.html')
    return redirect(template)
```

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ TodoDate }}</h1>
  <p>{{ TodoDescription }}</p>
  <p class="pubdate">{{ publishDate }}</p>
  <a href="delete/{{ Todo.description }}">Delete</a>
</div>
```

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "ToDo"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('details/<todo_description>', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('details/delete/<todo_description>',
         views.todo_delete, name='delete'),
    path('post', views.todopost, name='post'),
]
```

[image]

Comment: You did not pass the `Todo` object to the template.

Comment: Furthermore please make use of the `url` template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url Deleting objects should be done through a POST or a DELETE request, and `redirect(template)` makes not much sense, since you can not *redirect* to a template.

Comment: i tried using it but it was giving namespace errors i couldn't quite get a lid on

Comment: well it should be `{% url 'toDo:delete' valueForDescription %}`. Furthermore pleasse do *not* use a description, but a primary key, uuid, or slug.

Comment: alright thanks, that was my first option before description but i  had some issues somewhere  i would pass in id but it seemed to not be able to retrieve it from the db

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this

```
  <a href="delete/{{ TodoDescription }}">Delete</a>
```

If not pass Todo object from views.